# how to find centre value of a contiguous set of booleans

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have some simplified code below. I want to find the centre dict key for the `True` values. In the simple set of values `res` I think I could find the midpoint but I don't have a clue how to do that for a more disparate set of results `res2`.

**Code for res**

```
res = {"29": False, "30":True, "32":True, "31":True,  "33": True, "34": True, "35":False, "36":False, "37":False}



def findMiddle(input_list):
    middle = float(len(input_list))/2
    if middle % 2 != 0:
        return input_list[int(middle - .5)]
    else:
        return (input_list[int(middle)], input_list[int(middle-1)])


positives = []
for k,v in res.items():
    if v:
        positives.append(k)
print("positives : ", positives)
positives = [float(i) for i in positives]
ordered_positives = sorted(positives)
print(ordered_positives)



middy = findMiddle(ordered_positives)
print(middy)
```

**Code for res2**

```
res2 = {"1":True,
"29":False,
"30":True,
"32":True,
"31":True,
"33":True,
"34":True,
"35":False,
"36":False, 
"37":False,
"45":True,
"44":True,
"39":False}


positives2 = []
for k,v in res2.items():
    if v:
        positives2.append(k)
print("positives2 : ", positives2)
positives2 = [float(i) for i in positives2]
ordered_positives2 = sorted(positives2)
print(ordered_positives2)
middy2 = findMiddle(ordered_positives2)
print(middy2)
    
    positives = []
    for k,v in res.items():
        if v:
            positives.append(k)
    print("positives : ", positives)
    positives = [float(i) for i in positives]
    ordered_positives = sorted(positives)
    print(ordered_positives)
```

**Outputs**

positives :  ['30', '32', '31', '33', '34']

[30.0, 31.0, 32.0, 33.0, 34.0]

32.0

positives2 :  ['1', '30', '32', '31', '33', '34', '45', '44']

[1.0, 30.0, 31.0, 32.0, 33.0, 34.0, 44.0, 45.0]

(33.0, 32.0)

**Desired output for res2**

"32" or 32,

my code does give that, but I don't trust it to always give that for different data sets.

Comment: Can you provide what is the expected output for `res`? Also will there be only one contiguous set of True values?

Comment: Hi Kuro, I have updated question. I have an answer but I'm not 100% of it for res2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I can understand, this is a possible solution, to be tested with more input data and expected results:

```
positives = sorted([ k for k, v in res2.items() if v ])

n = len(positives)
if n%2 == 0:
  idx = n//2-1
else: idx = n//2

val = positives[idx]
print(val) #=> 32
```

The result is coming from this input:

```
res2 = {"1":True,
"29":False,
"30":True,
"32":True,
"31":True,
"33":True,
"34":True,
"35":False,
"36":False, 
"37":False,
"45":True,
"44":True,
"39":False}
```